# How to publish my MVC 3 web application onto IIS7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, publish

if possible I need total from the beginning utter beginner advice on how to get my ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor Visual Studio 10 web application live onto my IIS 7 webserver please?

I've never tried to publish this before, and wondering what I'm missing?

I've clicked "Publish" on Visual Studio Express 10, created a "published" version of the website. I've uploaded it to my webserver, however can't make it load on the net?

Appreciate some guidance please? (not sure how / what default documents work etc...?)

Comment: Does your server have MVC3 installed on it?

Comment: First things first, did you create the site in IIS? If so, were you able to access the website by IP or FQDN before publishing the site from Visual Studio? If so, after deploy are there errors? Have you turned customErrors="Off"?

Comment: I'm not sure if it does, is there a simple guide / way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By far the easiest approach is to use Web Application Deployment.

This blog by Scott Gu gives a great intro

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx

The article talks about web.config transformations (ability to have a .Release and a .Debug version of your web.config).  Later, that capability was generalized through an add-on package to work for any XML-structured file in your deployment (for example, I use it with NLog configuration files).

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

Comment: Thank you Eric, I'll have a read of that. Apologies for the ignorance, do I have to do anything to IIS7 (running on svr 2008) to allow this to all work?

Comment: @Harry - that walkthrough assumes many things, such as that you have a working site configured on the server, and MVC installed on it.  Do you have that much?

Comment: This is it, I've not installed MVC myself, and looking for absolute beginner advice on the steps I need to take. Where would I go to install MVC on IIS7? again, sorry for the ignorance.